# Parent class issue - UITableViewController doesn't work

Tags: objective-c, uitableview

When I access my Search View from my tab bar, the view gets loaded when SearchViewController interface is set like this:

@interface SearchViewController : UIViewController

but it crashes when I set it like this (although it doesn't crash when it is not accessed through the tab bar):
@interface SearchViewController : UITableViewController

Why? I need the UITableViewController as I have a table view that I access from the tab bar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found an answer. Your MainWindow.xib file should have a UITabBarController and four view controllers. But, only THE FIRST TWO tabs can be UITableViewControllers (or UIViewControllers), but none except the first two tabs can be UITableViewControllers.